# Using ES6 modules in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, module

Is there a way to

1. write my code using ES6 modules in `Express` app;
2. without reverting to `babel` or `@std/esm` ?

once I am committed to `app.js` of `Express`, I can't find a way to get out of it.

This seems like something that should be already on the web, but all I can find is above options (transpiling, esm).

Comment: Have you read this: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: More or less familiar with that article. The only path I see there is to use dynamic import(). I tried that but couldn't make it work. Like putting below in app.js. App runs, but url results in "not found". It pulls right object from module, but app.use() part as if hasn't happened. May be by the time this it is resolved it's too late? 

import('./routes/lecture.mjs')
  .then
  ( 
    lectureModule =>
    {
      app.use('/lectures', lectureModule.router );
    }
  )

Comment: You would need to show us the precise code you're trying to use for us to know what to suggest as a fix.  ESM modules can work just fine in the later versions of nodejs.  I've run programs using only ESM imports, but there are some compatibility issues with some ComonJS modules on NPM so unless you're using only modules that specifically support ESM import, you may have to do some troubleshooting to see what the issue is.

Comment: All I am trying to do is to have 
app.use('/someUrl', someRouter )
in app.js of Express. 
If I do this by the book, 
const someRouter = require('someModule') 
it works. But I prefer to have someModule in ES6 format instead of commonJS. And I would rather avoid using babel or @std/esm

Comment: If you're using TypeScript it should transpile your ESM imports for you. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With node.js, you HAVE to tell it that your main file you are loading is an ESM module.  There are a couple ways to do that.  The simplest is to just give the main file a `.mjs` file extension.

```
// app.mjs

import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(80);
```

Then, start your program with:

```
node app.mjs
```

This works - I just ran it with node v14.4.0:.  The others ways to do it are discussed in the link I previously gave you [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).  Per that documentation, there are three ways to specify you are loading an ESM module as the top-level module file:

1. Files ending in `.mjs`.
2. Files ending in `.js` when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module".
3. Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval`, or piped to node via STDIN, with the flag `--input-type=module`.

Comment: Well, encouraged by your experience, went ahead and converted everything to ES6, including \bin\www (I've been using express-generator). In the end sort of managed to make it work (converting default imports to names, hardcoding __dirname, etc). I'll see how well it works, though bit worried that some bugs will pop here and there. Alternative is to leave top layer (app.js) in CommonJS and switch to ES6 from routing down, that also worked. 
Wish it (Express) was ES6 by default and out of box. 
Thx for helping @jfriend00

Comment: Would love to know how to take this one step further with controllers app.use(require('./controllers'))

Comment: @GreggoryWiley - If you have a specific question about how to implement a controller, then I'd suggest you post your own question on that topic.